# How can I do a CTXSYS.CONTEXT full text search of a table that I am accessing over an Oracle database link?

Tags: oracle, full-text-search, synonym

I have a schema that contains a synonym to table connected by a database link (because the other schema has a different SID).  The table contains a CTX.CONTEXT index. When I try to run a query such as the following

```
select * from my_table c 
    where CTXSYS.CONTAINS(c.index_col, ' [ {ant} ]  ', 1) > 0
```

I get this error:

```
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-10599: column is not indexed
```

However, if I run the same query in the table's schema, I get results.  It turns out that CTXSYS.CONTAINS can't be called over a database link. How can I do a full text search using the synonym?

Answer (score 0):

I searched in many places for an answer.  One post suggested creating a function that would get the CONTEXT score for a row and return it.  However, that is slow, as the function is running the query once per row.

So, I created the following package that will run the search once, then cache the scores, making getting results very speedy.

```
create or replace
PACKAGE SEARCH_PKG AS
  TYPE t_scores IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY pls_integer;
  TYPE t_scores_by_search IS TABLE of t_scores INDEX BY VARCHAR2(1000);
  TYPE t_searches_done IS TABLE of BOOLEAN INDEX BY VARCHAR2(1000);

  FUNCTION search(i_unique_id NUMBER, i_text VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER;

END;
/

create or replace
PACKAGE BODY SEARCH_PKG AS

  search_scores t_scores_by_search;
  searches_done t_searches_done;

  FUNCTION search(i_unique_id NUMBER, i_text VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN   

    IF searches_done.exists(i_text) = FALSE THEN
      FOR c1 IN (SELECT score(1) text_score, my_table_id FROM my_table WHERE contains(index_col, i_text, 1) > 0)
      LOOP
        search_scores(i_text)(c1.my_table_id) := c1.text_score;
      END LOOP;
    END IF;

    searches_done(i_text) := TRUE;

    IF search_scores.exists(i_text) AND search_scores(i_text).exists(i_unique_id)  THEN
      RETURN search_scores(i_text)(i_unique_id);
    ELSE
      RETURN 0;
    END IF;
  END;
END SEARCH_PKG;
/
```

You may then run a query like the following to do a full text search:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE search_pkg.search(my_table_id, ' [ {ant} ]  ') > 0
```

Note that for every different search you do, more data is stored.  So, if you have long running connections, you may want to make another procedure in the package to clear the data structures.